# Mean of truncated distribution

Tags: mean, truncated-distributions

Is the mean of a left truncated distribution always greater than equal to the original mean? Or is that only for certain distributions?

Comment: Consider a contrapositive of this question: what will happen to the average of any group of numbers *when you include more numbers, all of which are smaller than any of the originals?*

Answer (score 3):

If the means exist in both cases, then 
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int x f(x)\text{d}x$$
is lower than the mean of the left truncated rv $X^T$ with left truncation $\mu$
$$\mathbb{E}[X^T]=\dfrac{\int_{x\ge \mu} x f(x)\text{d}x}{\int_{x\ge \mu} f(x)\text{d}x}=\dfrac{\int_{x\ge \mu} x f(x)\text{d}x}{\mathbb{P}(X\ge\mu)}$$Indeed
\begin{align}
\int x f(x)\text{d}x &= \mu + \int (x-\mu) f(x)\text{d}x\\
&= \mu + \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\mu (x-\mu) f(x)\text{d}x}^\text{negative} + \int^{\infty}_\mu (x-\mu) f(x)\text{d}x\\
&\le \mu + \overbrace{\mathbb{P}(X\ge\mu)}^{\le 1} \overbrace{\dfrac{\int^{\infty}_\mu (x-\mu) f(x)\text{d}x }{\mathbb{P}(X\ge\mu)}}^\text{positive}\\
&\le \mu + \dfrac{\int^{\infty}_\mu (x-\mu) f(x)\text{d}x }{\mathbb{P}(X\ge\mu)}\\
&= \mu + \mathbb{E}[X^T-\mu]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[X^T]
\end{align}